# how to overlap a top <div> and a bottom <div> into an image without generating ugly/messy white spaces?

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I have a top div, an image, and a bottom div in my html and I want to overlap the 2 divs into my image, the first div should cover some area in the top part of the image, and the bottom div should cover some area in the bottom part of the image, the div should be the one  covering the image (on front of display). how would I do that in a clean way (without leaving white spaces) and make it responsive in respect to the width of the view or parent div?

**here is my html**

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#image {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.rects {
  height: 100px;
}

#rect-top {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 194, 228, 0.75), rgba(214, 0, 203, 0.479));
}

#rect-bottom {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(214, 0, 203, 0.479), rgba(0, 194, 228, 0.75));
}
```

```html
<h1>Start</h1>
<div id="rect-top" class="rects"></div>
<img id="image" src="image-with-gradient.jpg">
<div id="rect-bottom" class="rects"></div>
<h1>End</h1>
```

**this is what I want to achieve:**

[image]

as you can see there is no white space before and after the **h1** tags

Comment: Someone ate your `<html>` tag. You can likely use negative margins on the center image for the overlap.

Comment: I tried your suggestion I added ```margin: -100px 0px;``` in the ```#image``` and it work adjusting the positions but the image is the one covering the divs, how would I make the divs cover the image instead?

Comment: Set a higher `z-index` on the one you want on top, such as `z-index: 200;`.

Comment: @Raxi thanks that worked, this is the first time I heard ```z-index```

Comment: Yea it's often best to avoid using it when possible. But it's intended purpose is exactly the thing you're trying to do, so here it's appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your image and overlapping divs in a div. Inside that, `position` your overlap div elements `absolute`.

As a sidenote, don't use `id` for styling purposes. Also note that any `id` in your page can only live on a single element; `id` must be unique per-document.

Instead of creating meaningless markup for the gradients, you can use the pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` here.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.image-container {
  padding: 50px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.image-container::before,
.image-container::after {
  content: '';
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container::before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 194, 228, 0.75), rgba(214, 0, 203, 0.479));
  top: 0;
}

.image-container::after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(214, 0, 203, 0.479), rgba(0, 194, 228, 0.75));
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Start</h1>
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/g/1920/1080">
</div>
<h1>End</h1>
```

This also makes the use of `z-index` obsolete because elements with `position: absolute` are automatically on top of unpositioned elements.

Comment: Is it just on my device or the new edited seems to display the bottom gradient wrong?

Comment: it seems that adding ```left: 0;``` solve that for the ```.image-container::after```, anyways this is a super clean solution thanks.